# UpdateProgress not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have an `UpdateProgress` and I'm trying to show a `loading gif` while post back
but this code doesn't work when I click the button.

There is nothing happens with with this code and no post back on button click.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" DynamicLayout="true">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="ImageWait" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/wait.gif" />
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" ValidationGroup="Valid1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>   

protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some code
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set UpdateMode of your UpdatePanel to Conditional
- Manually trigger AsyncPostBackTrigger to your controls inside UpdatePanel and give the ControlID and EventName that will fire:

  ```html
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
      </ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" 
              OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>   
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonSave" 
              EventName="Click" />
       </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  ```
- Give an associated UpdatePanel's ID to UpdateProgress:

  ```
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
      AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
  ```
- And you can test its working in events using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);`:

  ```
  protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // delay it for 3 milliseconds
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

     //... Here will be your logic
  }
  ```

Comment: I did these but not worked, the image not showed and no post back again..

Comment: I added System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); in button code - the image now seen - thanks.

Comment: The code snippet has two closing ContentTemplate elements.  There should be an opening one and closing one.

Answer (score 0):

by default (whan no value is set in the UpdateProgress control)

```
DisplayAfter="500"
```

If your postback is "too fast", UpdateProgress will not show...
Try setting it to:

```
DisplayAfter="1"
```

to check if it's working, and than set your desired value